# Backup exec LTO tape capacity shows as 17.8GB

Tags: backup, backupexec, tape, lto

I have come across administering a Backup Exec 10d system, and all its tapes show a `Total Capacity` of `17,8 GB` while showing a `Used Capacity` of e.g. `281GB`.

The tapes are LTO2 so they should have 200GB uncompressed, which matchs the 281GB shown above, but I can not trust teh amount of free space BackupExect tells me.

Any idea?

Comment: To be clear, you're looking at the `Total capacity` field and not the `Data` or `Bytes written` fields?

Comment: Correct: `Total Capacity` field. `Data` is not there and `Bytes Written` has two different vales. In the column `Bytes Written` is the amount of data stored (so `Used Capacity`), while in the tape properties `Bytes Written` is the total amount of data ever written to the tape, e.g. `463GB`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used BUE in some time now, but...

Since you mentioned 10d I almost said "upgrade" but since the tapes are LTO2, the tapes and drive/library's drivers are probably just as antiquated if not more so.

Things you can attempt:

1. First try using the BUE drivers for the tape drive, if you aren't already.  Make sure you have the latest tape drivers that 10d supports (from the BUE support site on Symantec).
2. If #1 doesn't work, you can try using the OEM drivers for the tape drive.  BUE doesn't prefer it, but sometimes it is necessary.
3. If it is an HP drive, you can download the HP Tape Tools: http://h18006.www1.hp.com/products/storageworks/ltt/index.html and diagnose through that software to verify that the drive's firmware is up to date, and that the tape tools show the right capacity.  You'll need a blank tape to run the tests with though.

Hope that helps.